# Unable to locate IP address and open port discovered by nmap

Tags: networking, nmap

I used the following nmap command on Ubuntu:

```
 sudo nmap -Av 192.168.0.0/16 1,2>/tmp/nmap.out4
```

Then I grep-ed the output:

```
grep "Discovered" /tmp/nmap.out4
```

This displayed, among other entries, the following:

```
Discovered open port 1723/tcp on 192.168.55.6
Discovered open port 2000/tcp on 192.168.55.6
Discovered open port 161/tcp on 192.168.83.2
```

I am on a network 192.168.1.0/24

I did a "ip a" on all the machines on my entire network and did not find IP addresses discovered by nmap which are listed above. Can you point out some possibilities?

**In response to comment by @harrymc:**

I do not know how to see "Connected devices" on the router. I have a DSL connection to a home-made Linux box which serves as a router.

arp -a displays:

```
 (192.168.1.93) at 00:1e:67:d6:33:25 [ether] on enp3s0
 _gateway (192.168.1.94) at 00:1e:67:d6:2d:c0 [ether] on enp3s0
```

Output of arp -n"

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.93             ether   00:1e:67:d6:33:25   C                     enp3s0
192.168.1.94             ether   00:1e:67:d6:2d:c0   C                     enp3s0
```

I am able to ping to both the "foreign" IP addresses.

Comment: These addresses may relate to devices that are connected to the router. Try: (1) In the router, examine  "Device List" (or "Connected Devices" etc). (2) See what say `arp -a` or `arp -n`. (3) Do `ping -a <IP Address>`. Please add the results of these 3 points to your post.

Comment: @harrymc Edited the question. I have accepted the answer below but I thought that the router/gateway to the Internet will not send packets out with local IP addresses.  SHould I have added a rule in iptables to block that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is that those devices are not on *your* network. Your network is 192.168.1.0/24 but you told nmap to scan 192.168.0.0/16 (i.e. the whole 192.168.x.x), meaning that 99% of the addresses it was told to scan were external to your network.

There is nothing that fundamentally limits "192.168" addresses to a single LAN – the packets from your 192.168.1.x to e.g. the 192.168.55.6 will easily cross your router and all further routers as needed, just like with a "public" destination address. About the only true restriction regarding "private" addresses is that they cannot be reached across the Internet between two different ISPs.

(In other words, you don't even need to check addresses of your devices; the fact that the discovered addresses are "outside" of your /24 subnet *directly indicates* that the router must've had to send packets out to another network.)

So if you're at home, you might've been scanning your ISP's internal network; if you're at a university, you might've reached some LAN at the opposite side of the campus; and if you were connected to a VPN, you might've been poking at something on the VPN server's end.

(You can probably run snmpwalk to find out what the "port 161" device is (not that you should); I have a feeling you found someone's printer, but it could just as well be an Ethernet switch or something.)

Comment: I get it now.  I thought that the router/gateway to the Internet will not send packets out with local IP addresses. Should I have a rule in the iptables firewall to block such packets?

Comment: As far as the router knows, those addresses _aren't_ local to you, so it just forwards them like anything else – but yes, it would be reasonable to have a firewall rule or more commonly a special route (`ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 unreachable`) that blocks packets to such addresses from leaving the network boundary. (The route would be a slightly better fit, as it automatically gets the correct priority and doesn't interfere with other subnets you might have, whereas iptables rules would need manual exceptions.) Larger networks commonly have unreach routes for all private address ranges.

Comment: (The central point here is that your router *does not automatically know* where your network boundary is – it doesn't know whether it's at the outer edge of your network or if it's somewhere in the middle with five more 192.168.x subnets surrounding it – so it has no grounds for refusing to forward such packets by default. Again, 192.168.x addresses are not inherently "local" to anything; they're routable across subnets and even across network boundaries.)